# How can I avoid going through this annoying procedure to get my Bluetooth speaker connected?

Tags: bluetooth

Every time I want to connect my Bluetooth speaker, I have to go through a fiddly annoying procedure. On initial connection it works with HSP/HFP (headset quality) but on A2DP (higher quality) there is only silence. I have to switch it from A2DP to HSP/HFP, then disconnect from it, then reconnect to it, then switch to it as an audio device, then switch it from HSP/HFP to A2DP. Then A2DP works.

Why does this happen and how can I stop it from happening?

I am open to upgrading software that might feature fixes for this and am open to automating the annoying procedure as a workaround.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @wjandrea Hey there, this is on 16.04 LTS.